# How do I go about creating a self-bot on discord? Without usage of discord.py but using the module requests in python?

Tags: python, automation, python-requests, registration, captcha

I decided to take on the task of an automatic registering program, which sends valid data to: ***https://discord.com/api/v6/auth/register***

This lead me to the process of registering a new account, using preservation of logs in google dev tools to see how discord handles the packets, which i most partly understand.

This lead me to getting to this point:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}

payload = json.dumps{
           "captcha_key": None,
           "consent": True,
           "email": "TestEmail@gmail.com",
           "gift_code_sku_id": None,
           "invite": None,
           "password": "Password",
           "username": "Username"}

session = requests.Session()
r = session.post('https://discord.com/api/v6/auth/register', headers=headers,data=payload)

print(r.text)
# the session instance holds the cookie. So use it to get/post later.
# e.g. session.get('https://example.com/profile')
```

Which then returns an invalid body error status code 400. Which i understand due to no captcha being given, however how would i request for that captcha display it to me or allow it to be present in some form of data to solve. Get that key and send it back into the payload. This is one of my first steps to many, the priority is being able to register an account using requests.

Finally i bumped into another problem such as fingerprint which i have no understanding of even when researching but coming to no result. If anyone has any ideas, solutions, or know which general direction to achieve this, it would be extremely helped. Lastly the reason why i did not want to use discord.py because i would like to get use to requests and enable myself not to do this just on discord but other websites.

I know this is against TOS however there will be no use of malicious purposes just needed a challenging place to start and a point of interest.

Sorry if any mistakes were made in the question, or in the actual program itself, i understand the majority of python and have experience however no experience in doing such tasks as these. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time today to understand how they are generated and found this!
Just submit a **POST** request to **https://discord.com/api/v8/auth/fingerprint**
Get data in JSON format.